# Xcode C++ автодобавление строк кода и коррекция

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Xcode C++ - Есть ли в Xcode автодобавление set и get функций? Автокоррекция?

Comment: совет: ставьте тэг `iOS` его больше людей смотрит

Comment: Вопрос, конечно, не очень. Но уж никак не опросник. Тем более, голосовать за его закрытие после того, как дан ответ совсем уж странно.

Answer (score 1):

Да есть.

1) чтобы сгенерировать get/set вам надо объявить property в интерфейсе класса, например:

```
@interface MyView : UIView
    @property BOOL myProperty;
@end
```

В этом месте Xcode для вас сгенерирует геттер и сеттер (никакого дополнительного кода или нажатия чего либо от пользователя не требуется), которые вы сможете вызвать одним из следующих способов:

**Геттер** (имеет то же имя что и проперти)

```
[self myProperty];
self.myProperty;
```

**Сеттер** (генерируется как set+название проперти с большой буквы; либо как `имя =` если использвать дот нотэйшн)

```
[self setMyProperty:YES];
self.myProperty = YES;
```

если надо поменять имя сеттера или геттера указываете в декларации проперти:

```
@property (getter=isMyPropertyTrue) BOOL myProperty;
```

Если надо чтоб проперти сгенерировала только гет метод, надо указать ее как readonly:

```
@property (readonly) BOOL myProperty;
```

Помните, что проперти объявленная в `.h` будет паблик, в `.m` будет прайвет (в ObjC нет протектед).

2) автокоррекция есть в очень ограниченном исполнении, например при попытке использовать неизвестный класс/метод вместо известного с подобным названием, IDE предложит замену; или если используется неподходящий тип данных, как то int на месте float и так далее в некоторых ситуациях будет предложено заменить. Хотя на самом деле Xcode с его автокомплитом и мнговенным указанием всех неизвестных классов/методов сильно в автокоррекции не нуждается.